# How to make draggable sprites do collide but not moving to new position?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to make game in Sprite Kit.And idea is to move sprites(in mine case boxes) with touch and drag.When boxes hit each other they should stay in place.I have set physicsBody.dynamics for all boxes to false.When box is touched it becomes dynamic = true .And when touch is ended box is set back to dynamic = false.Everything is working fine if I am dragging sprite(box)slowly.When I start dragging it fast it goes through other sprite's(boxes) with physicsBody.dynamic = false.

Am I thinking in right direction or this should be done differently?

Any kind of advice would be great for me.Thanks!

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

 //When box is touched it becomes dynamic

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation!) {
        if body.node?.name == "wall" {return}
        if body.node?.name == "wallRight"{return}
        else{
            body.node?.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            body.node?.name = "touchedBody"
        }
    }

}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

// Here is everything ok

    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
        if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location){
            guard let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode else {return}
            if sprite.name == "touchedBody"{
                if sprite.size.height>sprite.size.width{
                    let spritePositionY = sprite.position.y + location.y - previousLocation.y
                    sprite.position.y = spritePositionY

                }else{
                    let spritePositionX = sprite.position.x + location.x - previousLocation.x
                    sprite.position.x = spritePositionX

                }  
            }
        }   
    }

 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

// And here i think i have problem.

    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location){

            guard let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode else {return}
            if sprite.name == "wall"{return}
            if sprite.name == "wallRight"{return}
            if sprite.size.height>sprite.size.width{
                moveVerticaly(sprite, wallCeiling: wallCeiling, wallFloor: wallFloor)
                moves += 1
                sprite.name = nil
            }else{
                guard let sprite = body.node as? SKSpriteNode! else {return}
                moveHorizontally(sprite, wallLeft: wallLeft, wallRight: wallRight)
                moves += 1
                sprite.name = nil

            }
                sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration for all time:

```
enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
    case Boxes = 1
    case Wall = 2
    //case Enemy1 = 4
    //case Enemy2 = 8
    //case Enemy3 = 16
    //case Bullets = 32
}

func setPhysics(sprite:SKSpriteKit) {
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFromRect: sprite.frame)
        sprite.physicsBody!.mass = 1
        sprite.physicsBody!.friction = 0
        sprite.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false // set as you want
        sprite.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        sprite.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        sprite.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        sprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Boxes.rawValue
        sprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.Boxes.rawValue || CollisionTypes.Wall.rawValue
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
     if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionTypes.Boxes.rawValue &&
            contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == CollisionTypes.Boxes.rawValue) {
        print("boxes collided")
     }

}
```

Comment: ,Thank you.But when I have wrote line     sprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.Boxes.rawValue || CollisionTypes.Wall.rawValue
I have error : NO || candidates produce the expected contextual result type "UInt 32"

Comment: remove || CollisionTypes.Wall.rawValue if you dont have set a wall

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I need to set wall also.But even if I not,when dynamics are set to false there is not call of didBeginContact method  and sprites are passing through each other.If I set dynamics to true then there is call of didBeginContact method but sprites are pushing each other.I need to drag one sprite and rest of them should stay in place when dragged sprite hits them.Also all other sprites should be able to do same thing.

Comment: If I've understand try to remove <your object>.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask lines

Comment: I have tried that also but it seems that when two sprites are not dynamic there is not collision and there is not call of didBeginContact method they are just passing through each other.Because of that i have  set sprite dynamics in touchesMoved method to true,and in touchEnded method to false and that works fine if I am not moving sprites fast.

Comment: Look also for the flag multipleTouchEnabled = true ;)